# Variable global o de sesión?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Buen día, les explico un poco, actualmente tengo un sistema que manejara una sola base de datos con 4 empresas distintas en mysql por lo cual necesito saber que empresa selecciono el usuario pero a su vez el empleado puede estar usando 1 o mas empresas al mismo tiempo en distintas ventanas del navegador es por eso que no se que tipo de variable o como deba configurar mi aplicación para que me permita hacer esto. Tenia pensando hacer lo siguiente:

```
def set_current_company
   session[:company_id] = 1
   @company = session[:company_id]
end
```

Pero no se si sea adecuado hacer eso o bien si alguno conoce alguna forma de manejar ese tipo de situaciones correctamente ya que soy nuevo en el uso rails.

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No lo puedes guardar en una variable de sesión (tal como lo resaltó Ale), pero puedes obtener el mismo resultado enviando siempre el parámetro de la empresa que se esté navegando; y esto lo puedes hacer ya sea enviando por método `POST` o método `GET`.

#### Vista

**Utilizando `GET`**

En tu vista (o vistas) agrega la empresa actual los enlaces de navegación donde quieres que la empresa sea *recordada*, por ejemplo:

```html
<%= link_to "Mi link", mi_ruta_path(company: @company) %>
```

Dónde `mi_ruta_path` es el "helper" de rails que tiene la ruta a la que navegarás con ese link. Esto te dará como resultado el siguiente link (asumiendo que `@company` trae el valor `1`):

```html
<a href="/mi_ruta?company=1">Mi link</a>
```

No olvides especificar la ruta de `mi_ruta` como `GET` en tu archivo `config/routes.rb`.

**Utilizando `POST`**

Aquí es un poco más elaborado ya que necesitas utilizar un poco de javascript para enviar la forma desde un enlace, pero lo pudieras hacer en caso que quisieras evitar que se mostraran los parámetros en el url (e.g `/mi_ruta?company=1`).

En tu vista (o vistas) agrega la empresa actual en una forma dentro de `input` tipo `hidden` y genera una clase específica para los enlaces enlaces de navegación donde quieres que la empresa sea *recordada*, por ejemplo:

```html
<form id="mi-forma">
  <input type="hidden" name="company" value="<%= @company %>">
</form>

<%= link_to "Mi link", "#", class: "mi-clase" %>
```

Esto te dará como resultado el siguiente código `html`:

```html
<form id="mi-forma">
  <input type="hidden" name="company" value="1">
</form>

<a class="mi-clase" href="#">test</a>
```

Y, ahí mismo en tu vista, agrega el siguiente *script* (ejemplo con jQuery):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mi-clase').on('click', function() {
      $('#mi-forma').submit();
    });
  });
</script>
```

En este caso debes especificar la ruta de `mi_ruta` como `POST` en tu archivo `config/routes.rb`.

#### Controlador

Finalmente, en tu controlador (o controladores), únicamente debes leer el parámetro `company` y guardarlo en `@company`; este código es igual sin importar el método (`GET` o `POST`) que utilices para el envío del parámetro:

```ruby
before_action :set_current_company

...

private
def set_current_company
   @company = params[:company_id]
end
```

No olvides especificar a qué acciones deseas aplicar `set_current_company`.

Si vas a realizar esta acción en múltiples controladores, entonces puedes agregar el método `set_current_company` en `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` y así no necesitarás repetirlo cada vez.

---

#### Múltiples prámetros

Puedes enviar tantos parámetros como necesites, simplemente debes agregarlos al enlace (para `GET`) o en la forma (para `POST`); acá te muestro los ejemplos anteriores pero con un parámetro (`param2`) adicional:

**Vista utilizando GET**

```html
<%= link_to "Mi link", mi_ruta_path(company: @company, param2: @param2) %>
```

**Vista utilizando POST**

```html
<form id="mi-forma">
  <input type="hidden" name="company" value="<%= @company %>">
  <input type="hidden" name="param2" value="<%= @param2 %>">
</form>

<%= link_to "Mi link", "#", class: "mi-clase" %>
```

**Controllador**

El controlador también necesita modiricarse para recibir/asignar los valores del nuevo parámetro:

```ruby
before_action :set_params

...

private
def set_params
   @company = params[:company_id]
   @param2  = params[:param2]
end
```

Cambié el método para asignar las dos variables sin necesidad de agregar uno nuevo, pero podrías utilizar dos métodos si así lo deseas.

Comment: Genial esa información era justo lo que ocupaba saber, solo una duda al definirlo como get o post es necesario indicar cuantos parámetros voy a enviar o automáticamente me permite enviar los que yo desee? disculpa si la pregunta es algo tonta solo que soy muy nuevo en esto de rails

Comment: @DanielRomero Puedes enviar todos los que desees, solo debes agregarlos en el enlace  (si te decides por `GET`), separando con comas cada parámetro; o en la forma  (si te decides por `POST`) con un `input` por cada parámetro.

Comment: @DanielRomero Actualicé la respuesta para incluir ejemplos con dos parámetros. Espero te sirva.

Comment: @Gerry que gran respuesta!!!

Comment: Bien explicado @Gerry!

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @Gerry funcionó perfecto

Answer (score 0):

Si es variable de sesion, sera vigente solo para el usuario actual y los datos se compartirian igualmente para todas las ventanas del navegador. La informacionque estas mostrando deberia tener una referencia a que empresa pertenece, y con eso alcanzaria.

Comment: Es decir que dentro del controlador de la vista actual debería hacer un before_action set_company_id y así almacenar la empresa actual para el controlador que este usando? Es que lo que me gustaría es saber si puedo manejar con un mismo usuario varias empresas al mismo tiempo usando distintas ventanas o pestañas del navegador.

Comment: Tecnicamente es posible manejar varias empresas al mismo tiempo. No te conviene en sesion porque el dato es compartido.

Para eso en cada ventana tendrías que utilizar el id de la empresa en el querystring, por ejemplo.

La sesion usala principalmente cuando tengas que preservar datos que no sean muy confidenciales, que necesites tenerlos presentes todo el tiempo que el usuario este logueado.

Comment: Pudieras darme un ejemplo sobre como manejar ese id para mantenerlo y no perderlo en cambios de vistas, por ejemplo pasar de los usuarios de la empresa 1 a la nomina de la empresa 1 sin necesidad de tener que anidar las rutas o la única forma es anidando las rutas y estar enviando el id de la empresa en cada cambio de vista?

Comment: Desconozco rails, por eso no te doy un ejemplo de codigo.
Cada vez que abris una pagina indicas el id en la ruta. Y cada vez que recibis una peticion tiene que estar el id para saber a que empresa se refiere. Y para este caso creo que la solucion mas conveniente es, como bien dijiste, anidar las rutas incluyendo el id.

Comment: De acuerdo haré una prueba de esta forma, te agradezco tu ayuda. Y en un rato mas te cuento como me fue!